# Name a formula in align

Tags: align

If I have a (centered) formula/equation (in my example A+B=C) in align. How can I name this formula? I want the text to be on the right side. I know that hfill doesn't work.

```
\begin{align*}
    A+B=C     \hfill  \text{name of the formula}     
\end{align*}


 \begin{itemize}
 \item[$(1)$] ......
 \begin{align*}
 \tag{Not Centered}
  A+B=C
 \end{align*}
 \item[$(2)$] ....
 \end{itemize}
```

Comment: `\tag{name of the formula}`

Comment: But then the formula is not correctly centered.

Comment: Using `amsmath` package do `\[ A+B=C \eqno{\text{name of the formula}} \]`.

Comment: I don't understand what is the behavior you want if you use the `itemize` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming a formula is best achieved using `\tag{<stuff>}` (or the starred version which removes the surrounding parentheses). For centering an equation with regards to the text block when inside a list, you need to remove the left margin inserted by the list (`\@totalleftmargin`). Note that this margin is increased the deeper you nest lists.

Below I display the use of the latter using `\displayinlistundent` to insert a space to center the equation. Place this at the end of the equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\displayinlistundent}{\hspace{\@totalleftmargin}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  A + B = C
\end{align}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item A regular \verb|align|:
  \begin{align}
    A + B = C
  \end{align}

  \item A centred \verb|align|:
  \begin{align}
    A + B = C \displayinlistundent
  \end{align}

  \item A nested list
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item A regular \verb|align|:
    \begin{align}
      A + B = C
    \end{align}

    \item A centred \verb|align|:
    \begin{align}
      A + B = C \displayinlistundent \tag{Very important}
    \end{align}

    \item A nested list
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item A regular \verb|align|:
      \begin{align}
        A + B = C \tag{My equation}
      \end{align}

      \makeatletter
      \item A centred \verb|align|:
      \begin{align}
        A + B = C \displayinlistundent
      \end{align}
      \makeatother
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to use `\tag*`, you need to insert it using `\tag*{\llap{<stuff>}}` if you want things to remain centred:

```
\item A centred \verb|align|:
\begin{align}
  A + B = C \displayinlistundent \tag*{\llap{Very important}}
\end{align}
```

Comment: whether the left margin of display math is adjusted within lists depends on the document class.  the ams classes, for example, don't adjust; they always center on the whole line.  this is a publisher house style decision.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure what you are asking. But here is a try,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{align*}
  \tag{Not Centered}
  y = 3x
\end{align*}
\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
  \tag{Centered}
  y = 3x
\end{align*}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. But why doen't work this in the case of using align in itemize? I added an example.

Comment: This don't works if the name is very large. For example `\tag{This a larger name}` doesn't center the formula.

Comment: Hm, I see it. That's a problem.

Comment: And it makes problems in combination with itemize...

Answer (score 0):

I thought of the following to resolve the problem:

- Create a new command `\rtag` that redefines `\tag` for right alignment with

  ```
  \newcommand*{\rtag}[1]{\tag*{\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)}}}
  ```
- Use `\rtag` instead of `\tag`.

This doesn't affect the alignment of the formula but if the formula or its name are very long, there is a danger of overlapping.

Here the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\rtag}[1]{\tag*{\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{align*}
  \rtag{This a name larger than normal}
  y = 3x
\end{align*}
\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
  \rtag{Centered}
  y = 3x
\end{align*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to encase the second `align*` environment in a `center` environment?

Comment: @Mico i don't think so, the `center` environment can be omitted.

Comment: In other words, the `center` environment should be omitted, right? :-)